# Problem with Pyspark using *.ec2.internal ip instead of actual ip when querying Hive hdfs

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark

**How do I fix the querying address in Pyspark when using select statements?**

I have a problem that I feel like I am on the verge of fixing, but have no idea what I am doing wrong. I am trying to connect to a remote Hive instance on the aws emr service with pyspark through a vpc.

Here is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
spark = SparkSession \
  .builder \
  .appName("Python Spark SQL Hive integration example") \
  .enableHiveSupport() \
  .getOrCreate()
spark.sql("show tables").show()
```

It works perfectly to output the tables from my Hive hdfs. When I try to run the next command:

```
spark.sql("select * from default.demo_pharmacy").show()
```

I get the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o35.showString.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-123-1-12-123.ec2.internal
```

My problem is that I have no idea where pyspark is getting: **ip-123-1-12-123.ec2.internal**.

I have taken the following steps:

- ssh into the remote emr master spark/conf and changed all the instances of **ip-123-1-12-123.ec2.internal** to **123.1.12.123**.
- restarted hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager and spark-history-server in remote emr master
- configured hive-site.xml with:

  `<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://123.1.12.123:9083</value>
    <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>`

But nothing I am doing seems to be working. I keep getting the unknown host exceptions as I have my hive cluster behind an aws vpc.

So my question boils down to: **How do I fix the querying address in Pyspark when using select statements?** Thanks in advance for the help!